# I can't manually add foreign keys in golang gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am trying to add a foreign key manually in gorm but i get this error

```
db.Model(&models.Business{}).AddForeignKey undefined (type *gorm.DB has no field or method AddForeignKey)
```

am using postgres
i have tried

```
db.Model(&Business{}).AddForeignKey("cust_id", "customers(cust_id)", "CASCADE", "CASCADE")
```

Comment: Can you give this a try instead of `AddForeignKey`: https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html#FOREIGN-KEY-Constraints

Comment: Are you using gorm v1 or v2?

Comment: gorm.io/gorm v1.23.10

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with two solution that i know in **GORM**

**#1**

when you create model you do it like below:

```
type Business struct {
  Name         string
  CustomersID int
  Customers      Customers `gorm:"foreignKey:CustomersID"` // use CustomersID as foreign key
}

type Customers struct {
  ID   int
  Name string
}
```

**#2**

every time you want you can add foreign key like below

```
Client.Exec("ALTER TABLE business ADD FOREIGN KEY (cust_id)" +
        "REFERENCES customers (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;")
```